# CSRF in ADFS environment?

Tags: csrf, adfs

Is traditional CSRF PoC (e.g. [described here](https://portswigger.net/support/using-burp-to-test-for-cross-site-request-forgery)) effective for testing in this environment

Specifically if PoC only involved *one* account - of course, given presence of ADFS SSO...so not counting the final 3 steps described above.

Comment: The answer to this questions can only be opinions based. Thus it is of of scope.

Comment: @mentallurg can you expand on this? Interested to hear your take...

Comment: A 1000000 developers will say it is effective for them, the other 1000000 will say it is not effective for them. All of them will be right. If you use wording like "is effective", "is useful", "is good",  "is fast", "is secure", then very likely such question will have opinion based answers. Try to reformulate your question in such way that the answer does not depend on the opinions of those who answer it.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is already authenticated via ADFS they already have the security token and are already "logged in".

Therefore they will still be vulnerable to CSRF on any website.

I have to admit though, it depends heavily on how exactly the ADFS is configured and its relationship to the website at hand. So there is not enough information here to give a clear answer.